# NCP51460 alternatives

Tags: power, voltage-reference

The [NCP51460](http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=NCP51460) 20mA Precision Voltage Reference with it's wide input voltage range of up to 28V seems interesting for our current project, more-so considering the very competitive current price at Mouser/Digikey/RS. However, I am worried whether the part will be available (Location Germany) in the future. I have I also have not found a replacement part of a different supplier yet. Can someone suggest a similar part with input voltage range of at >=28V, output >=3.3V @ 5mA and similar or better accuracy?

Comment: Have you try with discrete (low cost LM4041/4051, FET and few resistors)? http://electronicdesign.com/power/efficiently-reduce-high-supply-voltages-accurate-low-voltage

Comment: @GRTech I will investigate this approach although it's quite a lot of parts...

Comment: I meant interesting. Sorry I was writing in a hurry from my mobile. In simulation I see a rather large drop-out of 800mV when Vin<Vref even with a logic level FET. Where does this come from?

Comment: Are you use FET like IRF7309 or FDS8958 or IRF7314?

Comment: No, I picked a logic level FET [863-5LN01C-TB-H](http://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/ON-Semiconductor/5LN01C-TB-H/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMshyDBzk1%2fWi5LYXAmq8rznS4PgrX1d1mk%3d)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13904/discussion-between-gr-tech-and-arne)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [LT6654](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1802003.pdf) - it operates up to 36V and produces 3.3V with up to 10mA output. It's also available in very low PPM/degC versions.

Comment: It's a bit expensive but at least an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a parametric search engine at a distributor such as Digikey. Here's what I got, and I don't think it looks very good for this part (nothing in the same package and nothing in the same price range), and non-stocked.

[image]

Can't you use some jellybean part like a [TLV431](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TLV431BCDBZR/296-17569-2-ND/705333) shunt reference?

Comment: I would like to avoid the 431 shunt references since they burn a lot of current at my maximum input voltage. The part only needs to supply <500uA which is even less than the minimum cathode current of the 431 shunt.

Comment: @Arne TLV431 only needs 80uA. It's not quite as cheap or available as the TL431, but still pretty reasonable, and you never need to worry about voltage rating or (reasonable) input transients with a shunt reference.

Comment: @Arne Failing that, maybe look at adjustable references. I don't think 3.3V is a very popular voltage for a series reference.

Comment: 3V would still work but 2V5 is definitely to an option.

Comment: TLV431 has a maximum cathode voltage of 6V which is may too low for my application.

Comment: You only need the max cathode voltage to be greater than the regulation voltage (3.3V). Everything else gets dropped across the resistor.